# an allocated value in DB returns null when retrieved

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

i had a null field in my column DB and i updated it, gave it a new value. when i reference it or try to show that value in my app, it still shows null. but when i check inside my DB, the field is not null. please help, i'm stuck

Comment: what is your query to output that data

Comment: I suspect the problem may be in some of the code. However, you haven't shown any code, so it's very hard to tell. If you change any *other* field, do you see that change? (If not, maybe you're looking at two different databases?)

Comment: the field in the DB is called ButtonImage, and i have assigned it an image path like this: '~Images/logo.png'  i used this line to bind it : <image Source = "{Binding ButtonImage}">

Comment: The field name doesn’t help us. Edit the question and show the code.

Comment: never mind, i got the answer